# understanding hierarchical python modules & packages

Tags: python

I am trying to work with python packages and modules for the first time and come across some import errors I don't understand.
My project has the following structure:

```
   upper
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── upper_file.py # contains "from middle.middle_file import *"
    └── middle
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── middle_file.py  # contains "from lower.lower_file import Person, Animal"
        └── lower
            ├── __init__.py
            └── lower_file.py # contains the Classes Person and Animal
```

I can run *middle_file.py* and can create inside the file a `Person()` and `Animal()` without any problems.

If I try to run *upper_file.py* I get a `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'lower'` error.

However, I have no trouble importing `Animal()` or `Person()` in *upper_file.py* directly with `from middle.lower.lower_file import *`

If I change the import statement inside *middle_file.py* from `from lower.lower_file import Person, Animal` to `from middle.lower.lower_file import Person, Animal` I can successfully run *upper_file.py* but not *middle_file.py* itself (and pycharm underlines the import in *middle_file.py* red and says it doesn't know middle)

In the end, I need to access inside of *upper_file.py* a class that is located inside of *middle_file.py*, but *middle_file.py* itself depends on the imports of *lower_file.py*.

I already read through [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) and [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) but just don't get how it works and why it behaves the way it does.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use relative import to accomplish this. [First link on Google](https://realpython.com/absolute-vs-relative-python-imports/#syntax-and-practical-examples_1) I found some practical example that could help you understand better.

On `middle_file` try to use `from .lower.lower_file import *`. It should solve the issue on `upper_file`.